# mysql database problem unable to connect python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, connector

I'm trying to connect my database to python code but always I got an error

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="*****",
    passwd="*******",
    )

mycursor = db.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE testdatabase")
```

the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 3, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
  File Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  \Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
  File Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
  File Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: not well I checked that question

Comment: None of the nearly 20 answers gives a clue? I suspect you are using the outdated `mysql-connector` package.

Comment: Thank you for helping , I find and answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is instead of installing `pip install mysql.connector` install mysql.connector-python which is `pip install mysql.connector-python`